# Multiple Ajax request by 1 click

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I have:

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        //blah
    })
});
```

I works just fine, above code make the ajax request just once, but when I have:

```
$('body').on('click', '#blah', function(){
    $.ajax({
        //blah
    })
});
```

This one sends the ajax request many times, sometime twice and sometimes more.
And I have to use the second code since the `#blah` object itself is added to the page by another ajax request, the first code doesn't work.

What is the problem? I have also used `return false;` at the end of the code, but not working... .

I would appreciate any kind of help.

---

`MORE INFO:`

Let's say I have a container, and there are buttons inside the container, the container itself has loaded by an earlier ajax request, something like:

```
$('a[rel="show_product_detail"]').on('click', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.companycontent').html('');
        $('.companycontent').addClass('members_content_loading');
        $('.companycontent').load('modules/companies/companies_tabs/product_details.php?product_id='+ product_id', function() {
            $('.companycontent').removeClass('members_content_loading');
        });
        return false;   
    });
```

Now in the container I have another buttons which cause the new content for the container, for those buttons I have to use the second code since the buttons are loaded via ajax. now by clicking on buttons inside the container, the ajax requests send many times(depends on the times which the container has reloaded).

Comment: Can you show how you're adding the new element from the ajax request?

Comment: I haven't seen $('body').on('click', '#blah', function() before.
What I have seen is $(document).on('click', '#blah', function().
Could you try that?

Comment: Can we see the HTML? from `#blah` up to `body`.

Comment: _"I have to use the second code since the #blah object itself is added to the page by another ajax request"_ - Does that other ajax request happen more than once and thus assign duplicate click handlers? That would explain the variable number of ajax requests when `#blah` is clicked (you'd get one for each time the other ajax ran).

Comment: @alkis - You might want to check the documentation for `.on()` before giving advice about its use.

Comment: Also check if you have multiple '#blah' in your code. That can make things messy sometimes.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but are you adding multiple elements with the same id? please don't do that, use a class instead ;)

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, non of the comments solved the problem.

Comment: If it's sent twice probably the event has been bound twice

Comment: @DavidFregoli I'm just testing it, it sends the ajax request on the number of the container has reloaded, how should I unbound(?) !?

Comment: @alkis $(document) does the same for me like $('body'), it didn't solve the prob

Comment: Does the `$('body').on('click', '#blah', function(){...` code appear once in your main script, or is that run inside a script that is part of the content loaded by the `$('.companycontent').load(...` code? If the latter, move it to your main script.

Answer (score -1):

after " success" is fired in your first request, you add your dynamic content to the page, once its done ,after the code you bind that to the click listener

```
$.ajax({
//...

success:function (data){
$(data).appendTo(".companycontent"); //inserts #blah
$("#blah").bind("click",function(){
//ajax code 
})

});
```

> or You can build a new object and make instances when you need

```
function AJAX(){
this.url="";
this.control="";
this.run = run;`
}

function run(){

$.ajax({

url:this.url,

success:function (data){
$(data).appendTo(".companycontent"); //inserts #blah
$("#blah").bind("click",function(){
//
});
}
});
```

and finally get new instance and init the object.
this object will be very nice if you modify it better

```
var test= new AJAX();
test.url="myajax.com/ajax";
test.control=Get_news(); // for example a click event
test.run();
```

Comment: I don't want to write all codes many times on many pages, this doesn't sound good